# Detecting checkbox event in jqGrid cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid, jquery-events

I'm exploring `jqGrid` in my journey of learning Javascript and jQuery and I manged to put a `checkbox` in a grid cell, awesome!

Here's what I have:

```
$("#myTable").jqGrid({
  colModel:[
     name:'cb', index:'cb', width:40, sorttype:"text", align:"center",
     edittype:"checkbox", editoptions:{value:"Yes:No"}, formatter: "checkbox",
     formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
     other stuff...
  ]
```

When a checkbox is clicked, how do I catch the event and determine the corresponding row data?

Also, when I click the checkbox is the underlying data on the client side updated (does the cb field switch "Yes"/"No")? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should not use `'cb'` as the `name` of the column because it is **reserved column name**. Other two reserved column names are `'subgrid'` and `'rn'`. Just use any other name if you don't want to have strange problems.

You have to bind the `click` event manually to your event handler. To do this you have some options.

You can bind `click` to all checkboxes inside of the `loadComplete` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6091535/315935) where are used jQuery to enumerate all checkboxes. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7210627/315935) shows a little more effective way which use the fact that DOM of `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` supports already native implemented `rows` and `cells` collections. So you can access `<td>` by `this.rows[iRow].cells[iCol]` inside of `loadComplete`.

One more way will be to use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) instead of `formatter: 'checkbox'` and use `onclick` attribute for binding.

**UPDATED**: If you use local data in the grid you have to update the corresponding value manually. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145342/315935) for example. It describes how to use `getLocalRow` or use `data` and `_index` internal parameters of jqGrid.

To get `id` of the row on which the user clicked you can use [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) of the current event `$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr('id')`.