# jqGrid: onselectrow not firing when checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I have a grid with different column types, including checkboxes.
I need to make the whole row editable when the user clicks on the corresponding row. so I set it like the following:

```
onSelectRow : function(rowId) {
            ...
            jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('editRow', rowId, {
                ...
            });
        },
```

This works when the user clicks anywhere on the row, but doesn't when he clicks on a checkbox which belongs to the row.
Can anyone tell me what did I miss?

Comment: Check out this post which has answer to your issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650547/detecting-checkbox-event-in-jqgrid-cell

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You write about "checkboxes". You should include `colModel`, which defines the columns. It's important to know *which formatter* you use and with which options.

Comment: here is the version I'm using : **jqGrid  4.6.0 - jQuery Grid**.

Comment: colModel:[
     name:'my_check_field', index:'my_check_field', width:67,  align:"center",
     edittype:"checkbox", editoptions:{value:"Yes:No"}, formatter: "checkbox",
     formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
   ...
  ]

Comment: Hi, I'm still having this issue, so if anyone could help, please!