# jqGrid. Custom button. How to redirect page?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have column 'Actions' that has images.

```
add = "<input type='image' src='/add_24.png' onclick='onAdd('"+row_id+"','"+subgridTableId+"')';/>";

$("#"+subgridTableId).setRowData(ids[i], { act: add });
```

How to redirect current page in **onClick** function?

I've tried all known methods. But current page just reload itself.

there is my onAdd func

```
function onAdd(id, pid) {

    window.open("www.msn.com");//1

    document.location.href = "sps/sites/main/export/_layouts/AddContractProperty.aspx";//2

    var form = $('<form>');//3
    form.attr('action', 'sps/sites/main/export/_layouts/AddContractProperty.aspx');
    form.attr('method', 'POST');

    // if(newWindow){ form.attr('target', '_blank'); }
    var input = $('<input type="hidden">');
    input.attr({ 'id': 'CID', 'value': cid});
    input.attr({ 'id': 'PID', 'value': pid});
    form.append(input);
    form.appendTo(document.body);
    form.submit();


}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you use `setRowData` to construct the data for the grid. Instead of that it's much more effectively to use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) instead. It you use `gridview: true` additionally you will not only simplify the code, but improve performance of it (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) for details).

To redirect the page to new location you need just assign `location.href` with full URL of new page. No `window.open` is needed. You can append the URL with additional parameters. The method works perfect if you need use HTTP GET to access to new page. If you need use form submitting with POST you can construct `<form>` dynamically of just use existing hidden form. In any way it's wrong to use mix all above methods.

Additionally I would recommend you don't use `onclick` attribute to start *global* function `onAdd`. Instead of that you can use `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` callbacks which will be called because of [event bubbling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow). Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) for a code example.