# How do I display text - like "Click Here" - in a specific column of every row...without using a button?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How do I present a value like "View" in a cell.

FYI - I dont need a button (assuming it is not a jqgrid requirement).

I am content with just using the "onCellSelect" event to do what I need whenever the particular cell is clicked.

I just want to know how to place text - like "View", or "Click Here", etc  within a specific column in each row.

I tried something like this, but, the text does not appear.
i.e.,

```
    -
    -
    -
    {name: 'view',              
    label: 'view',              
    index: 'view',              
    width: 100, 
    editable: false, 
    edittype:'text', 
    align: 'center', 
    editoptions: {value: 'View'}}
    -
    -
    -
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy. What you need to do is to use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). Typically the input data for the grid contains some data the the column and you need to display some other HTML fragment based on the input for the column or based from the input for another columns of the same row. You have more simple requirement. You need just place some fix text in one column. So you can skip all parameters (`cellValue`, `options`, `rowObject`) of the custom formatter and do something like

```js
{
    name: "view",
    width: 100,
    sortable: false,
    align: 'center',
    formatter: function () {
        return "Click Here"; // one can return ANY HTML fragment here
    }
}
```

You can use `onCellSelect` or `beforeSelectRow` to detect the click. I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935). The main difference in the choice between `onCellSelect` and `beforeSelectRow` is the possibility to prevent selection of the row of the grid by clicking on the "Click Here" text.

Comment: Thank you, Oleg.  That was precisely the simple explanation/example I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/ZQ4wd/2/

Add this scripts after your table is initialised.

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td').eq(1).text('Click Here');
});
```