# several call when I hit a action inside jqgrid with jquery

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid component inside my page and the rows of the grid are create with values and actions, for example:

```
colum:  name     adresss      job               edit

row 1:  jorge    my adress    architect        [value]
```

I populate the grid with several rows from a database and aech row have a value in column edit to the personal page for editing actions.

this value have this structure:

```
<div><span class="edit" idperson="' + items[i].id + '">Edit</span></div>
```

in the same script I put this:

```
$('.edit').live('click', this.clickedit);
```

and the function is:

```
clickedit: function(){

    $.ajax('person/personedit.htm', {
        cache: false,
        type : 'POST',
        data : { idperson: $(this).attr('idperson')},
        success : function(response){
            //some actions.....
        }
    });





},
```

in my java code I have a spring controller that recieve this call from jquery and do something.

The first time I clic the Edit action in a row all is OK, but after a while working with the application I see that a single edit action is called several times so the clickedit function execute 2, or 3 or 4 times and my java code are hit the same numbers of times.

any idea about this issue???

**UPDATE:**

I start to using onCellSelect now. But I have a problem. In a single cell I can put 3 differents action in this way:

```
var actions = 'editedOK ? '<div><span class="edit1" idperson="' + items[i].id + '" >EDITOK1&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="edit2" idperson="' + items[i].id + '">EDITOK2</span></div>' : '<div><span class="editnook1" idperson="' + items[i].id + '">EDITNOOK1</span></div>';
```

if actions = true I see in the same cell "EDITOK1  EDITOK2" and if actions = false I see in this cell "EDITNOOK1"

everyone of this actions have associates functions with differents behaviour when I clic in it.

If I use onCellSelect it´s possible to determinate when I hit EDITOK1, when I hit EDITOK2 and when I hit EDITNOOK1. More important is to determinate between EDITOK1 and EDITOK2.

Comment: first of all `live()` is deprecated now in present version of Jquery use `on() instead...And about ur problem it may be coz u are binding the event more then one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you calls `$('.edit').live('click', this.clickedit);` *multiple times*. It's the reason why `this.clickedit` handler will be called more as one time.

I recommend you don't use any explicit binding of `this.clickedit` callback. Instead of that you can use `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) for the corresponding code examples.

Comment: I start to use onCellSelect. my prob now: In 1 cell I put 3 action in this way: var actions = 'editedOK ? '<div><span class="edit1" idperson="' + items[i].id + '" >EDITOK1&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="edit2" idperson="' + items[i].id + '">EDITOK2</span></div>' : '<div><span class="editnook1" idperson="' + items[i].id + '">EDITNOOK1</span></div>'; 

if actions = true I see in the same cell "EDITOK1  EDITOK2" and if actions = false I see in this cell "EDITNOOK1".  How I can determinate when I hit  EDITOK1  and when I hit EDITOK2

Comment: please see the update in my question. thanks a lot for you quick answer

Comment: @JorgeInfanteOsorio: I would recommend you better to use `beforeSelectRow` as `onCellSelect` because you can return false from `beforeSelectRow` and prevent selection of the row if the user click on some action button. Now back to your main problem currently. The element `e.target` is the DOM of clicked element (the clicked `<span>`). Because you have multiple spans with different classes in the cell you can use `$(e.target).hasClass("edit1")` or `$(e.target).hasClass("editnook1")` to determine which span was clicked.