# hyperlink / button with custom function call in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to add a hyperlink / button in each row of jqgrid, that fires a custom javascript function. Tired of various trials.

```
jQuery('#ProductListGrid').jqGrid({
    url: '/Product/ProductListGrid',
    datatype: 'json',
    multiselect: true,
    height: 250,
    autowidth: true,
    mtype: 'GET',
    loadComplete: addlinks,
    colNames: ['ProductId', 'ProductName', 'edit'],
    colModel: [
      { name: 'ProductId', index: 'ProductId',key:true, width: 70, hidden: true, editable: true, size: 5 },
      { name: 'ProductName', index: 'ProductName', width: 70, editable: true },
      { name: 'edit', index: 'edit', width: 70},

    ],
    pager: jQuery('#ProductListGrid_pager'),
});
function addlinks() {
    var ids = jQuery("#ProductListGrid").getDataIDs();
    alert(ids);
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        be = "<a href='#' style='height:25px;width:120px;' type='button' title='Slet' onclick=\"ff()\" >Slet</>";
        jQuery("#ProductListGrid").jqGrid('setCell', ids[i],'edit','', { act: be });
    }
    //for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    //    jQuery("#ProductListGrid").setCell(i, 'edit', '<a href="#">edit</edit>');
    //}
}
function ff()
{
    alert("hi");
}
```

The code in addlinks in is getting executed but there nothing appears in the column. I tried using custom formatting also but I couldnot show custom text "Edit" and link click doesnot fire the js method.

Comment: Have you tried the `formatter`? if so can you share them or provide the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net)...

Comment: I added another column to grid, which shows link  { name: 'ProductId', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '/Product/ProductEdit/', addParam: '&action=edit' } }

Comment: I would recommend you to read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) which shows how to use 1) custom formatter to place some text/link/button in the column 'edit' and 2) how to use `beforeSelectRow` callback instead of `onclick` attribute to execute any JavaScript code on click on the link/button...

Comment: `beforeSelectRow` callback have the second parameter `e` which provide you information about the clicked element. `$(e.target).closest("td")` will be the clicked cell,  `$(e.target).closest("tr")` will be the clicked row,  `$(e.target).closest("td").attr("id")` will be the rowid and so on. `var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0]);` is the column number of the clicked cell. In any way I strictly recommend you to use `gridview: true` option (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935)) to improve performance. Usage of `addlinks` makes grid slow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call a formatter for edit column like below :

Add `formatter: addLink` to the last column :

```
colModel: [
      { name: 'ProductId', index: 'ProductId',key:true, width: 70, hidden: true, editable: true, size: 5 },
      { name: 'ProductName', index: 'ProductName', width: 70, editable: true },
      { name: 'edit', index: 'edit', width: 70,formatter: addLink},

    ]
```

add javascript function :

```
function addLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) 
{
  //to get row Id
  alert(options.rowId);
  // to get product Id
  alert(rowObject.ProductId);
  return "<a href='#' style='height:25px;width:120px;' type='button' title='Slet' onclick=\"ff()\" >Slet</a>";
}
```

More Information on [formatter here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter).

Comment: Thanks, this fires the method. Can you help me how to pass id to the function?

Comment: do you want to pass productId to ff function?

Comment: Yes. the product ID and row id as well, in case i need any other info

Comment: you can access any column of the current row using rowObject like rowObject.ProductId or rowObject.ProductName inside addLink function.

Comment: And use options to get row id like options.rowId