# RowBinding event in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

Is there any event like "`RowBinding`" in jqgrid. I need to add a `image` tag to a column of each row data in client side under some conditions.

Something like this,

```
 RowBinding: function (rowId, rowData) {
           //After manipulating the data it should get bind to the grid.
                }
```

If there is any alternative please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use custom formatter in the column where you need to place image. By third parameter (`rowObject`) of custom formatter you have access to *all* values of the row. If you need do some additional actions on `click` on the image you can use `beforeSelectRow` callback additionally. I would recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935).