# What is the exact reverse of onCellSelect function in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

My code -

```
 onCellSelect: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e)
  {
        jQuery("#createrule").click(function(){
        hidePopup();
        showPopUp6();
      });     
   onCellSelect:
```

},

What is the exact reverse of `onCellSelect` function in jqGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should don't register new `click` event handler every time if the user click in the grid.

jqGrid register `click` event handler one during creating the grid. So you can do some actions in case of user click on some cell of the grid. Parameters `rowid` and `iCol` helps you to identify which cell was clicked and the `e` parameter (the Event object of `click` event) could gives you even more information if required. jqGrid is Open Source project. So you can any time examine the source code to understand better what `onCellSelect` do and in which context it will be called. Look at [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2704-L2721) of code.

Just an example You can define the following formatter

```js
formatter: function (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<span class='myLink'>" + cellValue + "</span>";
}
```

in the column with the name "myColumn" and define the following CSS rule which uses `myLink` class

```css
.myLink { text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }
```

You will have "links" in the column.

To detect that the user clicks on such pseudo-link you can use the following `onCellSelect` callback

```js
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    var $self = $(this), colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    if (colModel[iCol].name === "myColumn") { // test for the click in myColumn column
        alert("OK here we can do something");
    }
}
```

The alert will be displayed on click everywhere in the column, not only on the link. If you want to detect clicking only on the link then we should test `e.tagret` which is the element which was clicked by the user:

```js
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    var $self = $(this), colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    if (colModel[iCol].name === "myColumn" && $(e.tagret).hasClass("myLink")) {
        alert("OK, link is clicked and here we can do something");
    }
}
```

So `onCellSelect` can be used to handle `click` event on every cell of the grid. If you need to suppress selection of the grid additionally then you should use `beforeSelectRow` instead of `onCellSelect`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) for example.