# Open file from shared path in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, anchor

I have a shared path for a PDF file. if i paste the path in address bar,the file opens in all browser perfectly. Below code working fine in IE 8, but not in Chrome and Firefox

**Code**:

```
function openPDF(file) { window.open(file, '_blank'); } 

function linkFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

    if ($.trim(cellvalue) == "" || cellvalue == null)
        return $.trim(cellvalue);
    else
        return '<a href="#" onclick="openPDF(\'file:' + rowObject["URL"].replace(/\\/g, "/") + cellvalue + '\')" >' + cellvalue + '</a>';
}
```

I am using this code in `JQgrid` to make link column.

Kindly help on this to make that working in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to assign `location.href` inside of `openPDF` instead of usage `window.open`. Moreover I think better to use `beforeSelectRow` (or `onCellSelect`) to set click event handler. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26861047/315935) and other.

Comment: it is working in IE8 but not in Other browsers.
my path looks like \\servername\foldername\name.pdf

Comment: @HbV2: Such URL is not real URL which will be used in production. Nevertherless you can paste such URL in web browser and see how it will be fixed. Fr example you will see `file://servername/foldername/name.pdf` in Chrome. So you can just use fixed syntax of the URL depend on the web browser which you use.

Comment: Found the issue. Since browser is sand boxed it wont allow the to open local file. Thanks for your answer