# Tooltip for jqgrid column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, tooltip

I have jqgrid coloumn on which I want to customize my tooltip just for one column while for others I need default tooltip.

Any leads ?

My column is something like the below

```
....
{
                            name : 'title',
                            index : 'title',
                            width : '20%',
                            align : 'center',
                            sorttype : false,
                            sortable : false
                        }
```

Comment: I think that you need just define `cellattr` callback in `colModel` for the column where the custom tooltip need shown. Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7408355/315935).

Comment: @Oleg I tried cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
              return 'title="hallo "';
          } But it still shows the default value only. Can you please help ?

Comment: Do you tried [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataWithCustomTitle.htm) which displays custom tooltip in "Clients" column (`name: 'name'` in `colModel`)? If you have problems in *your* code you should append your question with your more full code. I suppose that you placed the callback `cellattr` in the wrong place.

Comment: This is how I tried. name : 'title',
      index : 'title',
      formatter : function(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
       return rowObject.linkName;
      },
      width : '100%',
      cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
             return 'title="hallo "';
         },
      align : 'left',
      sorttype : 'text',

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use?** Some old versions don't have `cellattr` at all. Later version of jqGrid have small bug and the value from `cellattr` have to start with one space: `return ' title="hallo "';`. Try to add the space and to repeat your test.

Comment: @Oleg jqgrid version is 3.8.2. Even after adding space as you said I am not able to overwrite the tooltip value.

Answer (score 2):

### Tooltip for Header

If you want `tooltip` for **header** of column you can just add `title` attribute with **jquery** like this:

if your grid container this:

```
<div id="myJqgrid"></div>
```

then yout js will be like this:

```
$("#jqgh_myJqgrid_title").attr("title", "Can't sort my title!");
```

Header name selector `id` forms like this:

> `jqgh_<<grid_div_name>>_<<column_name>>`

### Tooltip for cell in column

If you need tooltip for column you can use `cellattr` function.

You can even create different `tooltip` for each cell in column base on cell or row value, becouse function have optional parameters: `rowId`, `cellValue`, `rawObject`  etc ([documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Acolmodel_options))

In your case you can do like this:

```
{
   name : 'title',
   index : 'title',
   width : '20%',
   align : 'center',
   sorttype : false,
   sortable : false,
   cellattr: function () { return ' title="Here is my tooltip on colCell!"'; }
}
```

Comment: Not for header. I need for column.

Comment: {
      name : 'title',
      index : 'title',
      formatter : function(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
       return rowObject.linkName;
      },
      width : '100%',
      align : 'left',
      sorttype : 'text',
      cellattr: function () { return ' title="Here is my tooltip on colCell!"'; }
     } Not working still :-(

Comment: @oleg knows all :) as always

Comment: @teovankot .. I need for header only how can I do?

Comment: @SarwarCSE first way should fit you

Comment: Yes it works thanks. but is there any built in method or property?

Answer (score 0):

The version 3.8.2 of jqGrid was published in 2010. It's really **very old**. The features like `cellattr` was introduced later in jqGrid 4.0 (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:change#jqgrid_4.0.0_changes_and_fixes)).

I would strictly recommend you to update it to jqGrid 4.7.0 or jqGrid 4.6.0.

Comment: Thanks for the appropriate guidance. Is there any way to add tool tip with the version I use ?

Comment: Only to set `title` attribute explicitly on every `<td>` of the column. For example you can use the following `loadComplete` callback: loadComplete: function () { $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(5)").attr("title", "some text"); } It will set `"some text"` tooltip on all of 5-th column of the grid. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6091535/315935) to get the index of the column based on the column name.

Comment: Thank you. Will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the data (xml, json ...) you could have hidden values in a column and used **cellattr** to indicate the value of each column.
For example if you have three columns:

```
//tooltip obtained from hidden column for the first column
{
    name : 'title',
    index : 'title',
    width : '20%',
    align : 'center',
    sorttype : false,
    sortable : false,
    cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rowObject) {
                   return ' title="' + $(rowObject).find('cell:eq(3)').text() + '"';
              }
}, 
//default tooltip obtained from hidden column
{
    name : 'subtitle',
    index : 'subtitle',
    width : '20%',
    align : 'center',
    sorttype : false,
    sortable : false,
    cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rowObject) {
                   return ' title="' + $(rowObject).find('cell:eq(4)').text() + '"';
              }
},
//here you can set as in the column subtitle or put the default tooltip that you want
{
    name : 'subtitle2',
    index : 'subtitle2',
    width : '20%',
    align : 'center',
    sorttype : false,
    sortable : false,
    cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rowObject) {
                   return ' title=" My default tooltip "';
              }
},
//hidden columns
{
    name : 'hiddenColumn1',
    index : 'hiddenColumn1',
    hidden: true,
},
{
    name : 'hiddenColumn2',
    index : 'hiddenColumn2',
    hidden: true,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use jquery to create “title” HTML attribute for tooltips.

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

```
jQuery("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq(0)").attr("title", "Column 1 header title");

jQuery("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq(1)").attr("title", "Column 2 header title");

jQuery("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq(2)").attr("title", "Column 3 header title");
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for a set custom tooltip:

```
{
name : 'title',
index : 'title',
width : '20%',
align : 'center',
sorttype : false,
sortable : false,
cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rowObject) {
               return ' title="' + $(rowObject)[3] + '"';
          }
```

},